# hdfs list and select the latest updated files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

Trying to work a solution for getting the latest updated data in the list of files in HDFS.

Explanation:

```
hdfs dfs -ls -l /tmp/workday1/list/date=20170101/
```

The command above displays the list of files inside the folder mentioned along with the respective attributes like owner, permissions, updated Time, etc.

Like the directory `date=20170101` there are other date's directories as well, daily data load has its date's directory respectively. But it's not necessary that the files updated in the older date's directories can be of older date only. The process running today, if contains some old date's files, will put those files in the older date's folder only.

I need to figure out that once the loads are completed, I create a list of all the files that got updated today. My only constraint is that I need to figure this out based on the updated timestamp attribute only. The file names doesn't contain any date factor.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would a code-based solution work or should it only be shell-based?

Comment: It's only the shell based I'm hoping for. Came through a java based solution here but that'll complicate my whole package.

Comment: Grep for a date...do you care about hours, minutes, seconds?

Answer (score 3):

I was approaching it the wrong way; below is my answer to this.

```
hdfs dfs -ls -t -r -R -d ${path-to-hdfs-area}/date*/ | grep $currentDate | awk '{print $8}'
```

Above command will give the list of directories, if the list of files plus directories are required, we can remove the `-d` option.

```
hdfs dfs -ls -t -r -R ${path-to-hdfs-area}/date*/ | grep $currentDate | awk '{print $8}'
```

where, `currentDate=` `date +%Y-%m-%d`

Answer (score 0):

```
hadoop fs -ls -t <hadoop_path> 
    | grep <todays_Date> 
    | awk '{print $(NF)}' 
    | awk -F/'{print $7}' 
    | awk -F='{print $2}' 
    | uniq
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts. That's especially important when there's already an answer that's been validated by the community. Under what conditions might your approach be preferred? Are you taking advantage of new capabilities?